# Play 2.1 Scala JSON parsing harder than Jerkson?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

With Jerkson, I was able to parse a String containing a JSON array, like this:

```
com.codahale.jerkson.Json.parse[Array[Credentials]](contents)
```

where contents was a String containing the following:

```
[{"awsAccountName":"mslinn","accessKey":"blahblah","secretKey":"blahblah"}]
```

... and I would get the array of Credentials.

(Brief diversion) I tried to do something similar using the new JSON parser for Play 2.1 and Scala using different data. For a simple parse, the following works fine. A case class (S3File) defines the unapply method necessary for this to work:

```
case class S3File(accountName: String,
                  bucketName: String,
                  endpoint: String = ".s3.amazonaws.com")

implicit val s3FileFormat = Json.format[S3File]
val jsValue = Json.parse(stringContainingJson)
Json.fromJson(jsValue).get
```

Let's reconsider the original string called contents containing JSON. As with all collections, an array of objects has no unapply method. That means the technique I showed in the the diversion above won't work. I tried to create a throwaway case class for this purpose:

```
case class ArrayCreds(payload: Array[Credentials])

implicit val credsFormat = Json.format[ArrayCreds]
val jsValue = Json.parse(contents)
val credArray = Json.fromJson(jsValue).get.payload
```

... unfortunately, this fails:

```
No unapply function found
[error]         implicit val credsFormat = Json.format[ArrayCreds]
[error]                                               ^
[error]      
/blah.scala:177: diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]
[error] starting with method ArrayReads in trait DefaultReads
[error]         val credArray = Json.fromJson(jsValue).get
[error]                                      ^
```

Is there a simple way of parsing an array of JSON using Play 2.1's new JSON parser? I expect the throwaway case class is the wrong approach, and the implicit will need to be instead:

```
implicit val credsFormat = Json.format[Credentials]
```

But I don't understand how to write the rest of the deserialization in a simple manner. All of the code examples I have seen are rather verbose, which seems contrary to the spirit of Scala. The ideal incantation would be as simple as Jerkson's incantation.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> case class Credentials(awsAccountName: String, accessKey: String, secretKey: String)
defined class Credentials

scala> implicit val credentialsFmt = Json.format[Credentials]
credentialsFmt: play.api.libs.json.OFormat[Credentials] = play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1@1da9be95

scala> val js = """[{"awsAccountName":"mslinn","accessKey":"blahblah","secretKey":"blahblah"}]""" 
js: String = [{"awsAccountName":"mslinn","accessKey":"blahblah","secretKey":"blahblah"}]

scala> Json.fromJson[Seq[Credentials]](Json.parse(js))
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Seq[Credentials]] = JsSuccess(List(Credentials(mslinn,blahblah,blahblah)),)
```

HTH,

Julien

Comment: You make it seem too easy :)